# file_get_contents doesn't work with some links

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to take the content of a site by *file_get_contents()*, but it doesn't work. I already tried to follow these codes [here](https://www.cb01.uno/lisa-e-il-diavolo-hd-1973/), but it doesn't work.
This is the code I have:

```
$url = "https://www.cb01.uno/";
$options = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

It returns nothing. I tried with other site like https://www.w3schools.com and it works, so the problem isn't the HTTPS

EDIT: I tried this solution [HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061801/http-request-failed-http-1-1-503-service-temporarily-unavailable) and now it display: 

*Not Found* 

*The requested URL /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl was not found on this server.*

Comment: When I run your code I get: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.cb01.uno/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. What are your error reporting settings?

Comment: I tried to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  before `$url = "https://www.cb01.uno/";` and I don't have any error

Comment: You may also need `ini_set('display_errors', true);`. Whatever, `file_get_contents()` can be hard to diagnose. You need to check the [`$http_response_header` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620124/http-requests-with-file-get-contents-getting-the-response-code).

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález, now it display this: _Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.cb01.uno/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable_

Comment: There you are. It's possible they're detecting you are a script and blocking you.

Comment: I also tried this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061801/http-request-failed-http-1-1-503-service-temporarily-unavailable and now it works but says _Not Found

The requested URL /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl was not found on this server._